# MapperParsingException[failed to parse [timestamp]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Invalid format:

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I've set up a basic ELK stack to prase and display apache logs. It has been working for the past 1 month but suddenly from last two days, elastic search is throwing the below error.

```
MapperParsingException[failed to parse [timestamp]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Invalid format:"16/Jul/2016:05:31:27 +0000" is malformed at "/Jul/2016:05:31:27 +0000"];
```

This is a default setup and I haven't made any custom changes in elasticsearch. The indexes are created date wise which is the default behaviour while setting up ELK.

If I stop logstash, then delete the index named **logstash-2016.07.16** and start logstash, it will work fine for a day. The next day it will throw the same error on the new index created (**logstash-2016.07.17**).

Versions :
Logstash - 2.3.2
Elasticsearch - 2.3.2
Kibana - 4.5

Answer (score 1):

Your format doesn't conform with Built-in formats of Elastic Search 2.3! Please refer 'Built In Formats' under https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html

I did face exactly the same issue! But I tweaked my PHP time object's format to be in accordance with Elastic Search Mapping!

Curl command to create mapping for the the field 'ClickTime' in a standard format :

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/telemetry/_mapping/DashBoardVisits?
pretty -d "{\"properties\" : {\"ClickTime\" : {\"type\" :\"date\" , \"format\" :
 \"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss\" }}}"
```

PHP code to create a time object matching the type and format of 'ClickTime' in Elastic Search :

```
$curtime = date_create();
$kibanadate = date_format($curtime,"Y-m-d H:i:s");
```